# Can't deploy SSIS package to SQL Server 2016 Express on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: sql-server, ssis, kerberos

I'm having difficulty deploying an SSIS package developed on my Windows 10 Home machine to the SQL Server 2016 Express instance on my Windows 10 Pro machine.

I have two computers in my home network setup, a Windows 10 Home machine where I'm doing VB.NET and SSIS package development and a Windows 10 Pro machine where I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Express.

In running the package deployment wizard, after selecting the destination server name I'm running into the Kerberos error "The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context".

Downloaded and ran the Kerberos Connectivity Troubleshooter on the Windows 10 Pro machine running SQL Server 2016 Express and got the error

> Unable to access User Principal information from the System

when trying to connect to the local SQL instance on that machine.

In the log file for the troubleshooter I get some more specific information but I'm running into a dead end with my online research:

> 3/26/2017 6:55:50 PM Info: Connect to WMI, \root\cimv2
>   3/26/2017 6:55:52 PM Error: Access of User Principal information failed System.ArgumentException: The supplied context type does not match the server contacted. The server type is ApplicationDirectory.
>
> at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoServerVerifyAndPropRetrieval()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType contextType, String name, String container, ContextOptions options, String userName, String password)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType contextType, String name)
>   at KerberosCM.WMIHelper.TryGetUser(SystemInfo mi, UserPrincipal& user)

What do I need to check or configure next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server Express does not have an SSIS server component.

Note here that Express does not have "SSIS Designer and runtime" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server.

The Developer edition, which is free, *does* have this but you aren't allowed to use it for production purposes.

Further to that, I don't think those editions of windows support Kerberos either.

Comment: Thanks for the information and the link.  I am not surprised to learn that I need an actual server in the picture for the Kerberos part but somehow I missed that SQL Express doesn't include SSIS services.  I'll put together a server machine and put SQL Developer on it to move forward.